# run binary service in Openshift and control it

Tags: ssh, openshift

I made a simple binary application like a clock and run it in server but when I close ssh connection,application will be closed.

But i want clock run all the time for example.

Then I made a simple service and I want to run it in server but I do not know how install,control and resume it after I close ssh connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an & after it to put it into the background, then you can close your ssh session and leave it running.  You could also (if the binary is in git) use an action hook to run it (but you still need to include the &), something like..

```
 $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/clock &
```

If it was located in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR directory.

Comment: I test your answer and run top command in another ssh session and check processes but when I close clock session,clock is no longer in process list.

Comment: Are you sure that your clock program is a long running program that is able to be put into the background?  Or is it something like a CLI program that needs user input to run?  Does it have a loop that keeps it running or is it a daemon etc?

Comment: My program is a simple loop that write time and its not a daemon,it should be for this usage?